# Creating a Home Server - Port Forwarding Issue

Tags: networking, webserver, router, portforwarding, dyndns

So I'm trying to setup my home server that is accessible from the Internet. I have created my Web site in ASP and configured my IIS. It works great on my local machine AND other computers on the local network can access it. I want to make it online, so that it can be accessed from elsewhere. I created an account on DynDns, and configured it to redirect the requests to my Internet IP. Then, I configured my router to forward all the incoming requests on port 80 to my local IP address, on which my Web site runs. However, when I go to my DynDns address, it redirects me to my router's home page instead. I have disabled my firewall (I know, not a good idea, it's just for testing purposes) but still no success. Does anyone have any idea what could be going wrong? I have a SMCWBR14S-N4 if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard of some routers that have reserved port 80 for there configuration pages. I think the general work around there is to run your webserver on a non-standard port like 8080, but I don't have a whole lot of experience with this, so it could be something else entirely. :)

Update: For any future readers, always remember to test your external address and port forwarding on a computer outside of the network the server is on.

Comment: Hm... I changed the port on my IIS but still no success. Good call though.

Comment: So, you tried connecting on a non standard port (e.g. name.dyndns.org:8080) and it still redirected you to the router's home page? That seems very strange to me.

Comment: Just thought of a couple more things. Did you update the router's port forwarding? Also, are you trying to connect from a computer connected to the same router as the server?

Comment: Well no, actually the browser couldn't connect to the new mappings. I typed in [myIPaddress]:8080 and the browser couldn't figure it out

Comment: I'm doing all of these on the same computer.

Comment: If you can, try to connect from another computer on a completely different network. I don't  think you are supposed to be able to connect using the external ip address from inside the network for security reasons.

Comment: OMG IT WORKED!! I'm so stoked right now! Thanks man! But I don't understand why I can't connect using the external ip address?!

Comment: Glad to hear it. Yeah, I've never understood that either. I've heard it's a security thing. Inside the network I just use the internal ip address of the server if I need to access it.